# Why am I getting a null UStaticMeshComponent when using Unreal Haxe

Tags: c++, haxe, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to use the following Haxe Unreal plugin. 
https://github.com/proletariatgames/unreal.hx

My class seems to compile without error but when I try to create a UStaticMeshComponent using the FObjectInitializer I keep seeing a null value when I trace this in the console.

**Here is the Haxe Extern that I'm using as a reference when calling CreateDefaultSubobject**

https://github.com/proletariatgames/unreal.hx/blob/9c4b4b512155b76911a06fbad170fd978b0e8ecd/Haxe/Externs/Common/unreal/FObjectInitializer.hx#L9

```
package unreal;

@:glueCppIncludes("UObject/UObjectGlobals.h")
@:noCopy @:noEquals @:uextern extern class FObjectInitializer {
  public static function Get() : PRef<FObjectInitializer>;

  @:thisConst
  @:noTemplate
  public function CreateDefaultSubobject<T : UObject>(Outer:UObject, SubojectName:FName, ReturnType:UClass, @:opt(ReturnType) ?ClassToCreateByDefault:UClass, bIsRequired:Bool=true, bAbstract:Bool=false, bIsTransient:Bool=false):T;

  @:thisConst
  @:uname("CreateDefaultSubobject")
  @:typeName public function CreateDefaultSubobject_Template<T>(Outer:UObject, SubojectName:FName, bTransient:Bool=false) : PPtr<T>;

  @:thisConst
  @:typeName public function SetDefaultSubobjectClass<T>(SubojectName:FName) : Const<PRef<FObjectInitializer>>;
}
```

**Here is my Haxe Unreal code.**

```
package fpsgame;

import unreal.*;

@:uclass
@:uname("AFPSObjectiveActor")
class FPSObjectiveActor extends AActor {
    @:uproperty(VisibleDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category=Mesh, meta=[AllowPrivateAccess="true"])
    var MeshComp:UStaticMeshComponent;
    var SphereComp:USphereComponent;

    public function new(wrapper) {
        super(wrapper);

        var init = unreal.FObjectInitializer.Get();
        MeshComp = init.CreateDefaultSubobject(new TypeParam<UStaticMeshComponent>(), this, new FName("MeshComp"), new TypeParam<UStaticMeshComponent>(), false);
        RootComponent = MeshComp;
        trace(RootComponent);
        // SphereComp = init.CreateDefaultSubobject(new TypeParam<USphereComponent>(), this, new FName("SphereComp"), new TypeParam<USphereComponent>(), false);
        // SphereComp.SetupAttachment(MeshComp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the C++ tag ?

Comment: Because Haxe is compiling to C++